# What's the difference between groupby.first() and groupby.head(1)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Both return a DataFrame of the first row of each group. When reading the API reference it says first "computes first group of values" but when looking at both outputs side by side I don't see a major difference.

Am I missing something?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,6,6,7,7],
                    'value'  : ["first","second","second","first",
                                "second","first","third","fourth",
                                "fifth","second","fifth","first",
                                "first","second","third","fourth","fifth"]})
```

[First API](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main difference is that `first()` will skip to the first non-null value, while `head(1)` won't.

If I drop `np.nan` into your example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,6,6,7,7],
                   'value'  : [np.nan,"second","second","first",
                               "second","first","third","fourth",
                               "fifth","second","fifth","first",
                               "first","second","third","fourth","fifth"]})
```

Then we have:

```
>>> df.groupby('id').head(1)
    id   value
0    1     NaN      # NaN is included
3    2   first
5    3   first
9    4  second
11   5   first
12   6   first
15   7  fourth

>>> df.groupby('id').first()
     value
id        
1   second          # NaN is skipped
2    first
3    first
4   second
5    first
6    first
7   fourth
```

(Also, as you see, `head()` resets the index.)

Answer (score 0):

I will add that first() is affected by the groupby's sort value while head() is not.

```
id  priority      
1   1          
1   2 
2   2
2   1
3   3
3   1
4   5
4   4

>>> groupby(['id']).first()
id  priority      
1   1          
2   1
3   1
4   4

>>> groupby(['id']).head(1)
id  priority      
1   1          
2   2
3   3
4   5
```

setting sort=False in the groupby will help preserve the original order when using first()