# what is different between groupby.first, groupby.nth, groupby.head when as_index=False

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

**Edit:** *the rookie mistake I made in string `np.nan` having pointed out by @coldspeed, @wen-ben, @ALollz. Answers are quite good, so I don't delete this question to keep those answers.*

**Original:**
I have read this question/answer [What's the difference between groupby.first() and groupby.head(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30004815/whats-the-difference-between-groupby-first-and-groupby-head1)

That answer explained that the differences are on handling `NaN` value. However, when I call `groupby` with `as_index=False`, they both pick `NaN` fine.

Furthermore, Pandas has `groupby.nth` with similar functionality to `head`, and `first`

What are difference of `groupby.first(), groupby.nth(0), groupby.head(1)` with `as_index=False`?

Example below:

```
In [448]: df
Out[448]:
   A       B
0  1  np.nan
1  1       4
2  1      14
3  2       8
4  2      19
5  2      12

In [449]: df.groupby('A', as_index=False).head(1)
Out[449]:
   A       B
0  1  np.nan
3  2       8

In [450]: df.groupby('A', as_index=False).first()
Out[450]:
   A       B
0  1  np.nan
1  2       8

In [451]: df.groupby('A', as_index=False).nth(0)
Out[451]:
   A       B
0  1  np.nan
3  2       8
```

I saw that `firs()' resets index while the other 2 doesn't. Besides that, is there any differences?

Comment: "np.nan" is a string. Replace it with an actual NaN entry. You'll see different results with `first()`.

Comment: holy moly! rookie mistake. I created data in textpad, copy and using `pd.read_clipboard()` to quickly load to pandas. I totally missed that it didn't turn `np.nan` to numpy `NaN`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The major issue is that you likely have the string `'np.nan'` stored and not a real null value. Here are how the three handle `null` values differently:

#### Sample Data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,2,2,3,3], 'B': [None, '1', np.NaN, '2', 3, 4]})
```

---

### `first`/`last`

This will return the first/last non-null value within each group. Oddly enough it will not skip `None`, though this can be made possible with the kwarg `dropna=True`. As a result, **you may return values for columns that were part of different rows originally**:

```
df.groupby('A', as_index=False).first()
#   A     B
#0  1  None
#1  2     2
#2  3     3

df.groupby('A', as_index=False).first(dropna=True)
#   A  B
#0  1  1
#1  2  2
#2  3  3
```

### `head(n)`/`tail(n)`

Returns the top/bottom n rows within a group. **Values remain bound within rows**. If you give it an `n` that is more than the number of rows, it returns all rows in that group without complaining:

```
df.groupby('A', as_index=False).head(1)
#   A     B
#0  1  None
#2  2   NaN
#4  3     3

df.groupby('A', as_index=False).head(200)
#   A     B
#0  1  None
#1  1     1
#2  2   NaN
#3  2     2
#4  3     3
#5  3     4
```

### `nth`

This takes the `nth` row, so again **values remain bound within the row**. `.nth(0)` is the same as `.head(1)`, though they have different uses. For instance, if you need the 0th and 2nd row, that's difficult to do with `.head()`, but easy with `.nth([0,2])`. Also it's fair easier to write `.head(10)` than `.nth(list(range(10))))`.

```
df.groupby('A', as_index=False).nth(0)
#   A     B
#0  1  None
#2  2   NaN
#4  3     3
```

`nth` also supports dropping rows with any null-values, so you can use it to return the first row without any null-values, unlike `.head()`

```
df.groupby('A', as_index=False).nth(0, dropna='any')
#   A  B
#A      
#1  1  1
#2  2  2
#3  3  3
```

Comment: it's a rookie mistake on `np.nan` as I explained in comment to @coldspeed. Your explain is excellent. Thanks. I upvoted and accept this answer

Answer (score 2):

Here is the different, you need to make the `np.nan` to `NaN` , in your original df it is `string` , after convert it , you will see the different

```
df=df.mask(df=='np.nan')
df.groupby('A', as_index=False).head(1) #df.groupby('A', as_index=False).nth(0)

Out[8]: 
   A    B
0  1  NaN
3  2    8
df.groupby('A', as_index=False).first() 
# the reason why first have the index reset, 
#since it will have chance select the value from different row within the group, 
#when the first item is NaN it will skip it to find the first not null value 
#rather than from the same row, 
#If still keep the original row index will be misleading. 
Out[9]: 
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  8
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. it's a rookie mistake on np.nan as I explained in comment to @coldspeed. I upvoted.