# python pandas dataframe resample.last how to make sure data comes from the same row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` looks like this ,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':range(9), 'col2': list(range(6)) + [np.nan] *3}, 
    index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=9, freq='T'))

df
Out[63]: 
                     col1  col2
2000-01-01 00:00:00     0   0.0
2000-01-01 00:01:00     1   1.0
2000-01-01 00:02:00     2   2.0
2000-01-01 00:03:00     3   3.0
2000-01-01 00:04:00     4   4.0
2000-01-01 00:05:00     5   5.0
2000-01-01 00:06:00     6   NaN
2000-01-01 00:07:00     7   NaN
2000-01-01 00:08:00     8   NaN
```

and when I perform `resample` by method `last`,

```
df.resample('3T', label='right', closed='right').last()
Out[60]: 
                     col1  col2
2000-01-01 00:00:00     0   0.0
2000-01-01 00:03:00     3   3.0
2000-01-01 00:06:00     6   5.0
2000-01-01 00:09:00     8   NaN
```

As can be seen above, the `6th minute` row has data on `col1`, so after resample, `col1` is filled with data on `6th minute` row, but `col2` is filled with `5th minute` row, is there is a way to make sure both data after resample come from `6th minute` row, that means if `col1` has data, the resample will not fill `col2`'s `NaN` with last, but simply leave it as is?

```
Out[60]: 
                     col1  col2
2000-01-01 00:00:00     0   0.0
2000-01-01 00:03:00     3   3.0
2000-01-01 00:06:00     6   NaN  <--- if there at least one col has data,the whole row will be used in resample
2000-01-01 00:09:00     8   NaN
```

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55583246/what-is-different-between-groupby-first-groupby-nth-groupby-head-when-as-index/55583395#55583395

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is how `last` work in `pandas` , it will return the `last` `notnull` value for group , if you want to get the last value (included nan, check with `iloc` with `apply` )

```
df.resample('3T', label='right', closed='right').apply(lambda x : x.iloc[-1])
Out[103]: 
                     col1  col2
2000-01-01 00:00:00     0   0.0
2000-01-01 00:03:00     3   3.0
2000-01-01 00:06:00     6   NaN
2000-01-01 00:09:00     8   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Also possible with `.nth(-1)` or `.tail(1)` using `ceil` to form the same groups:

```
df.groupby(df.index.ceil('3T')).nth(-1)
                     col1  col2
2000-01-01 00:00:00     0   0.0
2000-01-01 00:03:00     3   3.0
2000-01-01 00:06:00     6   NaN
2000-01-01 00:09:00     8   NaN
```