# Rows being combined when trying to show first instance of grouped-by data

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to show the first row by group (in this case, Car is the group). When I try to do this with the data below, however, my code shows 45 for the time of Fred (which is actually Betsy's time from the row below). I would like the output to show the first full row for Car A & the first full row for Car B even if they have np.nan in the time column.

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong and why my code would be combining row information like this?

Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd

test_df = pd.DataFrame({'Race':[1,1,1,2,2,2],'Car':['A','A','A','B','B','B'], 'Date':['5/1/2019','4/15/2019','3/1/2019','5/1/2019','2/1/2019','1/5/2019'],
                        'Driver':['Fred','Betsy','John','John','Frank','Frank'],'Time':[np.nan,45,46,47,44,43]})

test_df = test_df.sort_values(['Race', 'Car', 'Date'], ascending=[True, True, False]).groupby(['Car'], as_index=False).first()
```

Comment: This post has some more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55583246/what-is-different-between-groupby-first-groupby-nth-groupby-head-when-as-index/55583395#55583395

Comment: Thanks much, ALollz. This is a helpful post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.head(1)` instead of `.first()`:

Output:

```
   Race Car      Date Driver  Time
0     1   A  5/1/2019   Fred   NaN
3     2   B  5/1/2019   John  47.0
```

The difference between the two is how NaN is being treated: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49148885/8350440).

Comment: Thanks, Ji Wei! Sadly, I spent a lot of time trying to figure this out today and your response is great.

Comment: Glad it helped, appreciate if you could 'accept' my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use nth(0,dropna=False) instead of first()

```
test_df = test_df.sort_values(['Race', 'Car', 'Date'], ascending=[True, True, False]).groupby(['Car'], as_index=False,).nth(0,dropna=False)
```

Output

```
    Race Car   Date    Driver   Time
0    1   A   5/1/2019  Fred     NaN
3    2   B   5/1/2019  John    47.0
```

Comment: Great solution, Vishal. Thanks for taking time to answer my question. I tried to upvote but can't given my limited history on the site. Regardless, I appreciate your help! Thanks.