# Getting first non null value after group by function

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to return the first non null value of the utm_source column from each group after running a group by function.

This is the code I have written:

```
file[file['steps'] == 'Sign-ups'].sort_values(by=['ts']).groupby('anonymous_id')['utm_source'].apply(lambda x: x.first_valid_index())
```

This seems to return this:

```
anonymous_id
00003df1-be12-47b8-b3b8-d01c84a22fdf           NaN
00009cc0-279f-4ccf-aea4-f6af1f2bb75a           NaN
0000a6a0-00bc-475f-a9e5-9dcbb4309e78           NaN
0000c906-7060-4521-8090-9cd600b08974         638.0
0000c924-5959-4e2d-8757-0d10f96ca462           NaN
0000dc27-292c-4676-8a1b-4977f2ad1577         275.0
0000df7e-2579-4071-8aa5-814ab294bf9a         419.0
```

I am not quite sure what the values associated with the anon_id's are.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
{'anonymous_id': {0: '0000f8ea-3aa6-4423-9247-1d9580d378e1',
  1: '00015d49-2cd8-41b1-bbe7-6aedbefdb098',
  2: '0002226e-26a4-4f55-9578-2eff2999de7e',
  3: '00022b83-240e-4ef9-aaad-ac84064bb902',
  4: '00022b83-240e-4ef9-aaad-ac84064bb902'},
 'ts': {0: '2018-04-11 06:59:20.206000',
  1: '2019-05-18 05:59:11.874000',
  2: '2018-09-10 18:19:25.260000',
  3: '2017-10-11 08:20:18.092000',
  4: '2017-10-11 08:20:31.466000'},
 'utm_source': {0: nan, 1: 'facebook', 2: 'facebook', 3: nan, 4: nan},
 'rank': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2},
 'steps': {0: 'Sign-ups', 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan}}
```

So for each anonymous_id I would return the first (chronological, sorted by the ts column) utm_source associated with the anon_id

Comment: What do you mean by `value`? There's either `first`, which will not row-bind the values, or `nth`, which can return the first row with all non-null values, and values remain row-bound. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55583246/what-is-different-between-groupby-first-groupby-nth-groupby-head-when-as-index/55583395#55583395 is relevant

Comment: @ALollz sorry about that, reworded my question, the first non null value from the utm_source by anonymous id

Comment: Okay, so you just need an output Series (anonymous_id, utm_source), or do you need all of the other columns, just taking the first row where utm_source is not null within each group? It might help to add you expected output.

Comment: yes, the output would be a series of just the anon_id and source @ALollz

Comment: What's wrong with what you already ran?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So for each anonymous_id I would return the first (chronological,
>   sorted by the ts column) utm_source associated with the anon_id

IIUC you can first drop the null values and then [groupby first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df.sort_values('ts').dropna(subset=['utm_source']).groupby('anonymous_id')['utm_source'].first()
```

Output for your example data:

```
anonymous_id
00015d49-2cd8-41b1-bbe7-6aedbefdb098    facebook
0002226e-26a4-4f55-9578-2eff2999de7e    facebook
```