# drop duplicates by using groupy with a lambda function

Tags: python, pandas

My data is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{"icid":220,"product":6647,"updated_on":"2014-09-01"},
                   {"icid":220,"product":6647,"updated_on":"2014-09-03"},
                   {"icid":220,"product":6647,"updated_on":"2014-10-16"},
                   {"icid":826,"product":3380,"updated_on":"2014-11-11"},
                   {"icid":826,"product":3380,"updated_on":"2014-12-09"},
                   {"icid":826,"product":3380,"updated_on":"2015-05-19"},
                   {"icid":901,"product":4555,"updated_on":"2014-09-01"},
                   {"icid":901,"product":4555,"updated_on":"2014-10-05"},
                   {"icid":901,"product":4555,"updated_on":"2014-11-01"}])
```

My intended output is as follows:

```
icid,product,updated_on
220,6647,2014-10-16
826,3380,2015-05-19
901,4555,2014-11-01
```

I am using the following function,

`df.groupby(by=["icid"], as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x['updated_on'].max())`

But I get only dates. How do I get the rest of the columns?

Comment: So, you are working with a *dataframe*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['icid'])
```

but this will keep the first item. so you need to first order then remove duplicates.

```
df.sort_values('updated_on', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('icid').sort_index()
```

Group by is also a valid solution as ags29 suggested.

Comment: **If** the DataFrame is guaranteed to already be sorted, then you can just use `keep='last'` with your first `drop_duplicates` solution.

Answer (score 0):

`df.groupby(by=["icid", "product"])['updated_on'].max().reset_index()`

Comment: do i really need reset_index? Also what if I have many more columns

Comment: You could do `df.groupby(['icid', 'product'], as_index=False)['updated_on'].max()` here I think.

Comment: but it is grouping by product also? I have other columns such as origin, supplier etc. I want to groupby by id alone

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, I always found sorting first makes the rest of the code rather intuitive.

```
df.sort_values(by='updated_on', inplace=True)
df.groupby(['icid','product']).last()
```

Comment: `.tail(1)` would be better as it returns the row. `last` can reach across rows and grab the *last* non-null value if there is missing data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55583246/what-is-different-between-groupby-first-groupby-nth-groupby-head-when-as-index