# Calculate value difference using min and max dates

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate value growth/decline using the minimum date and maximum date. My data currently looks like this:

> ```
>     Code      Date        Value
> 0   A         2020-12-31  80122.0
> 1   A         2019-12-31  45472.0
> 2   A         2018-12-31  31917.0
> 3   A         2017-12-31  23432.0
> 4   B         2020-12-31      0.0
> ```

For Code A I need to keep the max (2020-12-31) and min (2017-12-31) dates as well as the values so I can calculate the difference later on. I have multiple codes and need to be able to apply the same logic to each one. Any suggestions on the best way to approach this?

Thanks

Comment: `df.groupby('Code')['Date'].agg(['min','max'])`. But do you need to calculate difference of the Date or of the Value?

Comment: Thanks Quang, aiming to calculate the difference of the Value. So A would be 56690.

Comment: Thanks very much - this gave me the result I needed.

Comment: You're not new to SO so you should know by now.. provide some actual code so we can more easily help you. 
`from io import StringIO`
`df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df_str), sep="\s+")` (copy paste your code)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case, you want to sort the date, then groupby and extract first, last:

```
 df.sort_values(['Code','Date']).groupby('Code')['Value'].agg(['first','last'])
```

Output:

```
        first     last
Code                  
A     23432.0  80122.0
B         0.0      0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

I would first `sort_values` then you can `drop_duplicates` on 'Code'. Using different logic for `keep` this allows you to get the first and last row (based on Date) within each 'Code', which you can then subtract to get the day difference and Value difference for each code.

```
df = df.sort_values(['Code', 'Date'])

(df.drop_duplicates('Code', keep='last').set_index('Code')
 - df.drop_duplicates('Code', keep='first').set_index('Code'))

#          Date    Value
#Code                   
#A    1096 days  56690.0
#B       0 days      0.0
```

---

Alternatively if you don't just need the difference and actually need the rows, then I would `concat` those together instead of subtracting. The main reason to avoid the `.first` aggregation is because it [**does not** guarantee data come from the same rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55583246/what-is-different-between-groupby-first-groupby-nth-groupby-head-when-as-index/55583395#55583395) (without specifying `dropna`) in the case of null values.

```
pd.concat([df.drop_duplicates('Code', keep='last').set_index('Code'),
           df.drop_duplicates('Code', keep='first').set_index('Code')],
          keys=['Last', 'First'], axis=1)

#           Last               First         
#           Date    Value       Date    Value
#Code                                        
#A    2020-12-31  80122.0 2017-12-31  23432.0
#B    2020-12-31      0.0 2020-12-31      0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

since you

> need to keep the max (2020-12-31) and min (2017-12-31) dates as well as the values...

, you can try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Code':['A','A','A','A','B'], 
                   'Date': ['2020-12-31', '2019-12-31', '2018-12-31', '2017-12-31', '2020-12-31'],
                   'Value': [80122.0, 45472.0, 31917.0, 23432.0, 0.0] 
                  }, )

df.loc[:, 'Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:, 'Date'])
```

is the df mentioned:

```
    Code    Date    Value
0   A   2020-12-31  80122.0
1   A   2019-12-31  45472.0
2   A   2018-12-31  31917.0
3   A   2017-12-31  23432.0
4   B   2020-12-31  0.0
```

so another way can be:

```
dictionary = {}

for code in df.loc[:, 'Code'].unique():
    dictionary[code] = {'Date min': df.loc[df.loc[:, 'Code']==code,'Date'].min(),
                        'Value min': df.loc[(df.loc[:, 'Code']==code)& (df.loc[:,'Date'] == df.loc[df.loc[:, 'Code']==code,'Date'].min()), 'Value'].values[0],
                        'Date max': df.loc[df.loc[:, 'Code']==code,'Date'].max(),
                        'Value max':df.loc[(df.loc[:, 'Code']==code)&(df.loc[:,'Date'] == df.loc[df.loc[:, 'Code']==code,'Date'].max()), 'Value'].values[0]
                                     
                       }
resume = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
resume = resume.transpose()
resume
```

that outputs:

```
    Date min    Value min   Date max    Value max
A   2017-12-31  23432.0   2020-12-31    80122.0
B   2020-12-31  0.0       2020-12-31    0.0
```